# Are there non-English books in the iBookstore?

Tags: books

All I'm seeing in the iBookstore are titles in English.

Are there any non-English (specifically Russian) public-domain books in the iBookstore?

Comment: The russian iBook store looks rather non-russian indeed. But there are non-english books available e.g. in german, french, italian etc.

Comment: Which national iBookstore is your Apple ID connected to? The US store has different titles than the UK store [and so on...](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2011/09/29/apple-adding-25-new-countries-to-ibookstore-market/)

Comment: Is there even such a thing as language-oriented iBookstores? On my iPhone I can only see one huge list of public domain books (some of them are in other languages as you said), but is it possible to filter by language at all?

Comment: @patrix, I see these options now on the iTunes, thanks. Sucks there's no Russian :-(

Comment: @bmike, not Russia, but I'd expect all public domain works to be available in all countries.

Comment: Like patrix said, the iBook store looks rather non-russian, but there are some Russian books on it. They are just difficult to find.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4058126?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did searches for Tolstoy, Pushkin, and Dostoyevski and found at least one Russian language book under each one.  Are these not there for you?

Comment: I meant books in the Russian language. iBooks has a variety of translations (even to languages other than English), but not the original works (at least none that I could find - if you succeeded, what were your exact search queries?). However, I did run your search, and for Pushkin there's a poem ("To the beauty who sniffed tobacco") in Russian. Not quite what I was hoping for, but it answers the question :-)